# An elementary question on integrating

Tags: calculus, integration

My question contains the following example :
Find the integral of
$$\frac{x^3-x+4}{x^4-2x^3+2x^2-2x+1} = \frac{A}{x-1} + \frac{B}{(x-1)^2} + \frac{C x + D}{x^2+1}$$

So why is $B$ not multiplied by $x$ with another variable say $E$ because the denominator is also from a 2nd degree?

Comment: Does this have anything to do with integration?

Comment: It's an example in my book for integration by parts.

Comment: it is $$3\, \left( x-1 \right) ^{-1}-2\, \left( x-1 \right) ^{-2}+{\frac {-2\,
x+1}{{x}^{2}+1}}
$$

Comment: The answer I already know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that we have 
$$\frac{A}{x-1} + \frac{B}{(x-1)^2}$$
which is indeed
$$\frac{Ax-A+B}{(x-1)^2}$$
which also can be written as
$$\frac{Ex+F}{(x-1)^2}$$
by defining $E = A$ and $F = -A+B$.

Or we can change some of the definitions to get:
$$\frac{A}{x-1} + \frac{Gx+H}{(x-1)^2} = \frac{(A+G)x+H-A}{(x-1)^2} = \frac{Ex+F}{(x-1)^2}$$
where we can define $E = A+G$ and $F = H-A$. These two should give same $E$ and $F$ in the end. But in this case, values for $A,G,H$ are not unique so I suggest you to use the first decomposition.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand now why I had difficulty understanding it.

Comment: Thx for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The general *partial fractions decomposition theorem* asserts that`

> Let $K$ be a commutative field, $\dfrac{F(x)}{G(x)}$ a rational fraction with coefficients in $K$. This fraction has a unique decomposition as a sum of a polynomial $Q(X)$ and rational fractions $\dfrac{A(x)}{P(x)^n}$, where
>
> - $Q(x)$ is the remainder in the euclidean division of $F(X)$ by $G(X)$,
> - $P(X)$ is irreducible in $K[X]$ and $\;\deg A <\deg \color{red}{P}$.
>
> Furthermore, assume the denominator has a decomposition into irreducible polynomials: 
>   $\;G(X)=P_1(X)^{n_1}\dotsm P_t(X)^{n_t}.$ 
>   Then
>   $$\frac{F(x)}{G(x)}=Q(X)+R_1(X)+\dots+R_t(X),\qquad R_i(X)\in K(X).$$
>   where  each rational fraction has the form
>   $$R_i(X)=\frac{A_{i,1}(X)}{P_{i}(X)}+\dots+\frac{A_{i,n_{i}}(X)}{P_{i}(X)^{n_i}},\qquad \deg A_{i,1},\dots,\deg A_{i,{n_i}}<\deg P_i. $$

Answer (score 0):

Because the theorem on [partial fraction decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition) of rational functions claims that such a decomposition exists. So, why bother to introduce a new constant $E$? Computations are simpler without it.

Comment: Because I didn't understand why it is like that.